# String Format Get Attribute Function

Tags: laravel

I try to create an attribute function in a model which returns a string result but I would like to change the format of the string.

Actually I have a number licence (`varchar` column), which is displayed like `17923457` and I would like to change the format to `17-92-3457`.

My function attribute actually is like:

```
public function getNumberAttribute() {

return $this->num_licence ; 

}
```

Someone knows how I can display that specific format? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: does this `17-92-3457` format is fixed format?

Comment: `getNumberAttribute` is just a getter?

Comment: Yes  it is ! The format will be always the same and the lenght of numbers will be always the same as the exemple

Comment: And yes it's just a getter method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another one linear approach using `vpsprintf`

```
public function getNumberAttribute() {

    return vsprintf('%d%d-%d%d-%d%d%d%d', str_split($this->num_licence));

}
```

for example :

```
$s = vsprintf('%d%d-%d%d-%d%d%d%d', str_split('17923457'));

print_r($s); // Outputs 17-92-3457
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure you are always going to have 8 digits, you can do

```
public function getNumberAttribute() {
    $first = substr($this->num_licence, 0, 2); //from position 0, take 2 digits
    $second = substr($this->num_licence, 2, 2); //from position 2, take 2
    $third = substr($this->num_licence, 4); //from 4 take the rest. 
    return $first . '-' . $second . '-' . $third; 
}
```

You get it. Use substring to split your varchar/string. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

Comment: i have an exeception now Undefined property: App\Licencies::$num_licence